# R lattice wireframe: how to increase the resolution of 3D graph

Tags: r, lattice, wireframe

I have a question which I don't have the answer to after a while of research.

```
temp.df<-subset(spread.df, x<5 & x>1 & y>1 & y<5)

wireframe((temp.df$z ~ temp.df$x + temp.df$y),
  scales=list(arrows=F), 
  screen = list(z = 40,x= -60) 
)
```

If I run this code, the x and y axes are from 2 to 4 with only one increment in between, which is 3.
This makes the graph very low res. Is there a way to bump the resolution without manipulating my original data set? By higher resolution, I mean subdividing the surface of the wireframe.

Thank you!

Comment: how many rows do you have in temp.df?

Comment: @Troy I have 9 rows in temp.df after subsetting the data. The graph looks very coarse because of the low number of data points on hand.

Comment: So you're basically asking for a 2D interpolation function.  Here's one: `akima::interp`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks alot! I think that's what I want. But it won't really change the surface. Do you happen to know any other regression function that can better represent my data?

Comment: You might try scouting around for a 2-D spline function, but Idon't know of one offhand.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks again! Yea, I'm going for some 2D spline func. numeric math here we go again:D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK here is how you can interpolate the surface with the `akima` package. By default it will give you a 40x40 grid, based on the existing surface:

```
require(akima)
require(reshape2)

temp.df<-expand.grid(x=2:4,y=2:4,z=0)
temp.df$z<-rnorm(9,10,3)

surface<-melt(interp(temp.df$x,temp.df$y,temp.df$z)) # melt() stretches out the surface to x,y,z as you've put into the original example
flat<-surface[!is.na(surface$X1)&!is.na(surface$X2),] # drop the NAs

#CONVERT SCALES BACK (INTERP GIVES YOU A 40x40 grid over the existing range)

points<-data.frame(x=min(temp.df$x)+(flat$X1-1)/(40/diff(range(temp.df$x))),
                   y=min(temp.df$y)+(flat$X2-1)/(40/diff(range(temp.df$x))),
                   z=flat$value)

wireframe((points$z ~ points$x + points$y),
          scales=list(arrows=F), 
          screen = list(z = 40,x= -60) 
)
```

[image]

Comment: Just promise you didn't need my comment above to get this answer :-)

Comment: Same thought at the same time, I think!

Comment: you guys are awesome! thanks alot for the work! points$z ~ points$x + points$y, is there a better regressional approach than this one here? I know I also used this one, but am just curious if there's another one that can better represent the data.